# AOSP ROMs Video Playback Capability

Tags: video, stock-android, samsung-touchwiz

I have one problem with AOSP roms and I consider this as the biggest one.
I have a Galaxy S3 I9300 running Stock 4.3 deodexed, zipaligned etc.

Now with this ROM I am able to play almost all types of video files...Why is this not possible with AOSP roms?

I have always seen people installing different types of Apps (MX Player, VLC Player etc. etc..) to get all the videos playing...
But TouchWiz plays almost all types of videos out of the box...As of now I don't have any third party video player installed on my phone...

I am a big fan of CM, but refrain from installing it just because of this one reason!

Can someone please explain this to me...would be great !!
And please correct me if i am wrong...

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's down to Samsung's vide player being pretty decent at formats, rather than the ROM itself, but afaik Samsung have modified the player to need the TW framework. I'm open to correction though.

Comment: It could be that the stock ROM uses some video decode hardware on the phone, which third-party ROMs lack drivers for. Just a guess though.

Comment: Related question with my answer: [What media formats are supported in Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/124065)

Answer (score 2):

**AOSP Video Playback**

Samsung's Touchwiz framework includes Samsung's own Video Player for Android. It's a decent player and covers a lot of different video formats.

AOSP (Android Open Source Project) ROMs come with the 'Stock' video player, which does not seem to have the wide array of features that Samsung provide.

**Samsung Video Player APK:**

I found a link to the apk for Samsung Video Player.  [Here is the player](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2289735)

As you said, you would have to install VLC, MX or an alternative player on AOSP to enable more video formats. I think the trade off of downloading an app, vs reinstalling the laggy, bloated Touchwiz is an easy choice, but it depends on what you prefer. It'd personal choice really.

---

**Galaxy S5 Video Player**

You can actually install Galaxy S5 apps on your S4/Note 2/3 as well.

[This XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=51332805&postcount=189) has the apk files for Galaxy S5 applications, including **Video Player**

---

**Added Bonus: Other Samusng Apps**:

[This XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1632639) has Samsung apps you can flash via custom recovery. However, it requires a custom recovery, and the Video player is not listed. Here are the apps you can install, perhapst he Samsung App Store would have the Video Player:

[Samsung apps store](http://forum.xda-developers.com/show...35&postcount=5)

[Polaris office](http://forum.xda-developers.com/show...postcount=1479)

[Touch Wiz 4 HD Launcher](http://forum.xda-developers.com/show....php?t=1539879)

[Touch wiz clock package](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/themes-apps/ported-touchwiz-clockpackage-apk-v2-4-t1639750)

[Samsung Task Manager](http://forum.xda-developers.com/show....php?t=1529223)

[Memo (not S Memo)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/show....php?t=1529223)